# Sorting an Array properly without arsort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to sort an array that has this form :

```
Array
(
    [18] => 9
    [14] => 4
    [53] => 9
    [10749] => 4
    [28] => 9
    [12] => 6
    [878] => 7
    [35] => 8
    [10769] => 1
    [9648] => 1
    [10751] => 1
    [27] => 1
    [80] => 3
)
```

The `arsort` function gives me :

```
Array
(
    [53] => 9
    [28] => 9
    [18] => 9
    [35] => 8
    [878] => 7
    [12] => 6
    [14] => 4
    [10749] => 4
    [80] => 3
    [27] => 1
    [10769] => 1
    [9648] => 1
    [10751] => 1
)
```

That's good but the thing is that when values are the same I would like to get them sorted by their `keys`, is that possible ? so i would get :

```
Array
(
    [18] => 9
    [28] => 9
    [53] => 9
    [35] => 8
    [878] => 7
    [12] => 6
    [14] => 4
    [10749] => 4
    [80] => 3
    [27] => 1
    [9648] => 1
    [10751] => 1
    [10769] => 1
)
```

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: I would suggest exploring the PHP manual more. A quick search would lead you to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a solution using php functions instead of the very slow bubblesort

```
    

$arr = array(
    '18'    => 9,
    '14'    => 4,
    '53'    => 9,
    '10749' => 4,
    '28'    => 9,
    '12'    => 6,
    '878'   => 7,
    '35'    => 8,
    '10769' => 1,
    '9648'  => 1,
    '10751' => 1,
    '27'    => 1,
    '80'    => 3
    );

print_r($arr);

arsort( $arr );
print_r($arr);


$last = null;
$tmp = array();
$result = array();
foreach( $arr as $k => $v ) {
    if ( $last && $v != $last ) {
        krsort($tmp);

        foreach ( $tmp as $kt => $vt ) {
            $result[ $kt ] = $vt;
        }

        $tmp = array();
    }
    $tmp[$k] = $v;

    $last = $v;
}

krsort($tmp);

foreach ( $tmp as $kt => $vt ) {
    $result[ $kt ] = $vt;
}

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean you don't want to use

```
rsort( ) – Sorts a Scalar array in reverse order
arsort( ) - Sorts the Values in an Associative array in reverse order
krsort( ) - Sorts the Keys in an Associative array in reverse order
```

you can try bubble sort

```
function bubble_sort($arr) {
    $size = count($arr);
    for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j<$size-1-$i; $j++) {
            if ($arr[$j+1] > $arr[$j]) {
                swap($arr, $j, $j+1);
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}

function swap(&$arr, $a, $b) {
    $tmp = $arr[$a];
    $arr[$a] = $arr[$b];
    $arr[$b] = $tmp;
}

 /* test bubble sort */


$arr = array(1,3,2,8,5,7,4,0);

print("Before sorting");
print_r($arr);

print("After sorting");
print_r(bubble_sort($arr));

  ?>
```

Comment: How is this relevant? It doesn't affect the keys at all, and the keys are what he is trying to sort for elements which are equal. He's also trying to sort descending, not ascending.